# Adding Times New Roman font in Okular

Tags: 22.04, fonts, pdf, okular

I got a PDF with two fonts that aren't embedded: *Arial* and *Times New Roman*. On Okular, they are substituted by other fonts which I don't like. Then, I've added those Microsoft fonts to my machine with `sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`. It looks like *Arial* is now correctly used but not *Times New Roman* (see PDF properties below).
[image]

Under `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/`, I do see the fonts:

- Times_New_Roman_Bold_Italic.ttf
- Times_New_Roman_Bold.ttf
- Times_New_Roman_Italic.ttf
- Times_New_Roman.ttf

Is there a way to force Okular to use it?

Comment: Just an FYI:   Don't forget [Ubuntu 21.10 is in it's last days of *support*](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/06/01/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-14-2022/) so plan your time to *release-upgrade* whilst you have *days* left, and not *hours*.

Comment: Thanks. I've upgraded to 22.04 but there is still the same problem.